# How to set timeout to JSONP?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I have some JSONP in my application, & I want to set timeout for them. 
How can I set it?

it maybe something like this, if it is possible :)

```
Ext.util.JSONP.request({
url: mhid.dashboard.hbf.controller+'/get_dashboard'
,method: 'POST'
,timeout : 50000 // TIMEOUT
,callbackKey: 'jsonp_callback'
,params:{
    'site' : site
    ,'fleet' : fleet
    ,'sn' : sn
    ,'format' : 'json'
}
,callback: function(response, opts) {
    var obj = response;
    tpl.overwrite('content', obj);
    loadMask.hide();
}
,failure: function(response, opts) {
    alert('Failure');
}
```

});

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible using JSONP - you should take a look at the [Ext.Ajax](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.Ajax) class.  Also, POST is not possible using JSONP (refer to [the Sencha forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?126126-AJAX-or-JSONP)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement your own timeout and execute the failure callback:

```
var failureCallback = function() {
    // MUST remove the current request, 
    // or it will not dispatch any subsequent new JSONP request
    // unless you refresh your page
    delete Ext.util.JSONP.current;

    alert('Failure');
};

Ext.util.JSONP.request({..}); // as usual 

var failureTimeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
    failureCallback();
}, 30000);
```

- **discard the timeout** if your request is **success**
- **discard current request** if the request has **timed out**